# Looking for a nice image library

Tags: php, image-processing

**Update:**  I'm not looking for a wordpres plugin. I'm currently developing an application which is just using Wordpress as a CMS. I need a standalone function to upload images, and resize them to the sizer I need.

---

I need a library for uploading and resize iamges. I want to store the images in folders, and store image reference in database.

I've looked around and read several posts. But I can't seem to find specific suggestions on libraries to use, or tutorials.

I want to avoid using a huge framework like CodeIgnite. I feel it's a bit overkill when I only need something for handling images. Or am I wrong?

I'm using Wordpress as CMS Framework.

I hope someone can guide me to some concrete examples.

Comment: Codeigniter seems like a framework, which by itelsef, is enough to run a blog. I don't need that since I'm using Wordpress and some it's functions.

Comment: In fact wordpress is an blogging script and i'm not sure we can classify it as a framework. When we look at php frameworks such as Zend Framewrok, symfony, cake php, etc, codeigniter is the lightest one. That's why i wrote "CI = huge?" :)

Comment: Ok, I might be confusing the termonology Framework. .NET can be a framework which an CMS is run on. But I'm making my own termonology... CMS Framework :)

Answer (score 4):

**wideImage** is great and pretty simple:
http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wiki/MainPage

Comment: This is more in the line of what I need. Not to too well documented on how to use though. But I'll figure it out :) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is thre a method for uploading files? WideImage only seems to handle images already saved to a file.

Comment: Oh! Sorry it hasn't a method for uploading files. I didn't read that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress checkout wp plugins @ [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins) 
BTW I'm using [nextgen gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery)

Comment: I'm currently using SimpleViewer - love it :)

Comment: So why did you ask that question?

Comment: Because the upload must be based on user login. User A must not be able to se users B's images (or handle them). Also, I want to make something that is CMS independant.

Comment: I think you must add this comment to question ;)

Answer (score 0):

shameless plug for my own (if you can't find a good wordpress plugin, which you should be able to): http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com

Comment: Nice lib. if I need to make thumbnails ;)

Comment: Yeah, like I said... it would work for you (since you can do resizing and stuff), but there's more than likely an existing wordpress plugin out there :)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention **[class.upload.php](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm)** library from **verot.net**
is not well programmed, but has a lot of features:

- with one uploaded file, you can do as
  many copies, convertions, resizing
  you want.
- you can resize each image dimension,
  or both, keeping the image ratio or
  not.
- you can choose to resize an image
  only if it is bigger -or smaller-
  than the wanted sizes
- you can manipulate the image in many
  ways, play with colors, add borders,
  labels and watermarks...
- its use is simplistic but powerful
- you can work on uploaded files or
  local files, useful for batch
  processing
- Flash uploaders are fully supported
- MIME type detection is very
  comprehensive
- more than 60 documented configuration
  settings
- a lot of variables are set up during
  the process. You can retrieve all
  these values after a process.
- error messages are understandable,
  and a variable log allows you to see
  what the class does.
- it is already widely used on Internet
- it is free :)

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use a simple upload script to upload the image in a temp folder. Then I will handle the image using the suggested library and store them in the correct folders.